# how to get the real file contents using TFilestream?

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

i try to get the file contents using TFilestream:

```
procedure ShowFileCont(myfile : string);
var
tr : string;
fs : TFileStream;
Begin
   Fs   := TFileStream.Create(myfile, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone); 
   SetLength(tr, Fs.Size);
   Fs.Read(tr[1], Fs.Size);
   Showmessage(tr); 
   Fs.Free;
end;
```

I do a little text file with contents only:
aaaaaaaJ“њРЉTщЂ®8ЈЏVд"Ј¦AИaaaaaaa

1. And save this file (using AkelPad) with 1251 (ansi) codepege
2. Save with 65001 (UTF8) codepage.

these to files has different size but there contents is equal - i oped them both in notepad and they both has the same contents

But when i run ShowFileCont proc it shows to me different results:

1. aaaaaaaJ?ЊT?8?V?"?A?aaaaaaa
2. aaaaaaaJ“њРЉTщЂ®8ЈЏVд"Ј¦AИaaaaaaa

Questions:

1. how to get the real file contents using TFilestream?
2. How to explain that these 2 files has different size but the content (in notepad) is equeal?

Add: Sorry, i didn't say that i use Lazarus FPC and string = utf8string

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with charsets and encodings.

Comment: For ANSI encoded file (string): `ShowMessage(AnsiToUTF8(tr));` Read this for details about encodings: [LCL Unicode Support](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/LCL_Unicode_Support)

Comment: TFileStream shows you the real content. Notepad shows you an interpreted view of these contents. Your question should be, how to get these interpreted contents ;o)

Comment: Abelisto.
Yes you are right, it works but in some cases:
For 1251 file ShowMessage(AnsiToUTF8(tr)) - show correct, but for UTF8 file ShowMessage(AnsiToUTF8(tr)) - show false, but ShowMessage(tr) show correct.

Comment: That is why i must somehow detect the file's codepage.
And if the file will be ex. any not 1251 or utf8 codepage?

Comment: You cannot detect the code page from the file. You need to know what the code page is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why do the files have different size?

Because they use different encodings. The 1251 encoding maps each character to a single byte. But UTF-8 uses variable numbers of bytes for each character.

> How do I get the true file contents?

You need to use a string type that matches the encoding used in the file. So, for example, if the content is UTF-8 encoded, which is the best choice, then you load the content into a UTF-8 string. You are using FPC in a mode where `string` is UTF-8 encoded. In which case the code in the question is what you need.

Loading an MBCS encoded file with a code page of 1251, say, is more tricky. You can load that into an `AnsiString` variable and so long as your system's locale is 1251 then any conversions will be performed correctly.

But the code will behave differently when run on a machine with a different locale. And if you wanted to load text using different MBCS encodings, for example 1252, then you cannot use this approach. You would need to load into a byte array and then convert from 1252, say, to UTF-8 so that you could then store that UTF-8 in a `string` variable.

In order to do that you can use the [`LConvEncoding`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/lconvencoding/index-5.html) unit from LCL. For example, you can use `CP1251ToUTF8`, `CP1252ToUTF8` etc. to convert from MBCS to UTF-8.

> How can I determine from the file what encoding is used?

You cannot. You can make a guess that will be accurate in many cases. But in general, it is simply impossible to identify the encoding of an array of bytes that is meant to represent text.

It is sometimes possible to take a file and rule out certain encodings. For example, not all byte streams are valid UTF-8 or UTF-16 text. And so you can rule out such files. But for encodings like 1251, 1252 etc. then any byte stream is valid. There's simply no way for you to tell 1251 encoded streams apart from 1252 encoded streams with 100% accuracy.

The `LConvEncoding` unit has [`GuessEncoding`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/lconvencoding/guessencoding.html) which sounds like it may be of some use.

Comment: Thanks, David Heffernan, now i do not check your code, but it seems to me the right way in my case.
But how i may get the file codepage?
Becuase i want some universal solution, not depending of file codepage. Ex. like text editors, notepad, akelpad.

Comment: I saw - In Lazarus i didn't find TEncoding class.

Comment: Text files don't necessarily contain the code page. You are expected to know how the text is encoded. There is no universal solution.

Comment: I don't think there is a TEncoding class in FPC, and to the best of my knowledge, it's harder in FPC to convert from an ANSI MBCS code page to a Unicode encoding. To an extent, you are suffering from tagging your question Delphi and failing to explain that you are actually using FPC. I deduced that you were using FPC because the facts you presented indicate that the `string` that you use is UTF8 and therefore you cannot be using Delphi.

Comment: Yes, i have just delete tag Delphi.
If Text files don't necessarily contain the code page. But how than AkelPad always show the codepage for any, not only text files (ex. doc, xls ets...)?

Comment: You can guess the code page with reasonable accuracy. But it's not fool proof. If the choice comes down to UTF-8 or MBCS, you could first check to see if the file is valid UTF-8. If not, assume it is MBCS using the system locale. But how could you expect to tell the difference between 1251 and 1252, say? No program can do that.

Comment: Thank you very much David Heffernan. I have just too find this unit in Lazarus dir. yes in LAzarus there is functions like systoutf8 and if GuessEncoding return to me cp1251 i may apply systoutf8. 
Is any difference between utf8 and utf8bom (i have found files with them in my dir)?

Comment: `UTF8ToUTF8BOM` will add the UTF-8 BOM to the front of the string. And `UTF8BOMToUTF8` strips the BOM. The BOM is Byte Order Mark. Websearch to find out more. I'm not sure there's any more that I can add. I think that I answered the question as fully as I can.

Comment: Yes i think now i understand ang get the answers to my questions, thanks!

Comment: It's interesting how AkelPad detect the code page... Because i try save file as console codepage (866 for me) and  GuessEncoding detect it like 1251, but AkelPad shows correct 866..

Answer (score 1):

Their contents are obviously *not* equal. You can see for yourself that the file sizes are different. Things of different size are never equal.

Your files might *appear* equal in Notepad because Notepad knows how to recognize certain character encodings. You saved your file two different ways. One way used an encoding that assigns one byte to each of 256 possible values. The other way uses an encoding that assigns between one and six bytes to each of more than 10,000 possible values. Some of the characters you saved require more than one byte, which explains why one version of the file is bigger than the other.

`TFileStream` doesn't pay attention to any of that. It just deals with bytes. Depending on your Delphi version, your `string` variable may or may not pay attention to encodings. Prior to Delphi 2009, `string` stored one byte per character. As of Delphi 2009, `string` uses two bytes per character, so your `SetLength` call is wrong, and everything after that is pointless to investigate much further.

With one byte per character, your `ShowMessage` call is not going to interpret the string as UTF-8-encoded. Instead, it will interpret your string using whatever your system code page is. If you know that the string you've read is encoded with UTF-8, then you'll want to convert it to UTF-16 prior to display by calling `UTF8Decode`. That will return a `WideString`, and you can use any number of functions to display it, such as `MessageBoxW`. If you have Delphi 2009 or later, then the compiler will insert conversion code for you automatically, if you've used `Utf8String` instead of `string`.

Comment: I think in this case `string` is UTF-8 because this is FPC

Comment: Sorry, i didn't say that i use Lazarus FPC and string = utf8string

Comment: David Hefferman: because it is Lazarus and showmessage is a GUI function. FPC string=default system codepage.